# All column shows same data in multicolumn listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi all In my application I am showing multicolumn listview (list had 3 columns), but in my application it is showing all columns same vaue. My listview layout is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingTop="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C20000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ltp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/down" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/perChange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C20000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ltp1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/down" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/perChange1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#C20000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ltp2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/down" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/perChange2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
     final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.srListView);
    lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));


public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ltp);
            holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.perChange);

            holder.txtName1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Name1);
            holder.txtCityState1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ltp1);
            holder.txtPhone1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.perChange1);

            holder.txtName2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Name2);
            holder.txtCityState2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ltp2);
            holder.txtPhone2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.perChange2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        System.out.println("position::" + position);

        holder.txtName
                .setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getStockCode());
        holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getLtp());
        holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getPerChange());

        holder.txtName1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getStockCode());
        holder.txtCityState1
                .setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getLtp());
        holder.txtPhone1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getPerChange());

        holder.txtName2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getStockCode());
        holder.txtCityState2
                .setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getLtp());
        holder.txtPhone2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getPerChange());

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCityState;
        TextView txtPhone;

        TextView txtName1;
        TextView txtCityState1;
        TextView txtPhone1;

        TextView txtName2;
        TextView txtCityState2;
        TextView txtPhone2;
    }
}
```

It shows me output as

[image]

Now here it shows all column same data, but what I want is to show all column different data, How to do this? Any help/suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Thank you Sam but Now there is issue if Name is large then my output look as: Suppose Vishal becomes Vishalllllllllllllllllllll

[image]

Comment: I suggest simplifying your layout to one box and using a GridView.

Comment: use a gridview rather than a listview

Comment: Can I use three rows in that one box which is in gridview? If yes can you show me any sample/tutorial . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use three rows in that one box which is in gridview? If yes can you show me any sample/tutorial .

Here is how to modify your existing code example to use a GridView.

**First** simplify your layout to one box, save it as `grid_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#C20000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ltp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/down" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Notice that I combined the last TextView and ImageView, you may need to adjust this.)

**Second** simplify your `getView` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // Change the layout that is loaded
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.Name);
        holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ltp);
        holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.perChange);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    System.out.println("position::" + position);

    SearchResult result = searchArrayList.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(result.getStockCode());
    holder.txtCityState.setText(result.getLtp());
    holder.txtPhone.setText(result.getPerChange());
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtCityState;
    TextView txtPhone;
}
```

**Last** Change these references (and any others that you may have):

```
final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.srGridView);
gv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation and simplification, because of some technical problem I can't implement it right now, Tommarow in morning I will do this. Once again thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gets are the issue.

```
holder.txtName2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getStockCode());
        holder.txtCityState2
                .setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getLtp());
        holder.txtPhone2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getPerChange());

holder.txtName1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getStockCode());
```

Do a debug / break point on the gets I believe your code will mean that the "position" int will be the same for your three box's on each row. Hence it returns the same data and puts it into each of the boxes in that row meaning you have duplicates.

You will want to do something like

```
 holder.txtName2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                    .getStockCode());
            holder.txtCityState2
                    .setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getLtp());
            holder.txtPhone2.setText(searchArrayList.get(position)
                    .getPerChange());

    holder.txtName1.setText(searchArrayList.get(position+column2dataoffset)
                    .getStockCode());
```

But I agree with the comments, a grid layout will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your existing code may this help you...

```
if((position * 3) <= getCount()){
    holder.txtName
            .setText(searchArrayList.get(position * 3).getStockCode());
    holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position * 3).getLtp());
    holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position * 3)
            .getPerChange());
}

if(((position * 3) + 1) <= getCount()){
    holder.txtName1.setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 1)
            .getStockCode());
    holder.txtCityState1
            .setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 1).getLtp());
    holder.txtPhone1.setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 1)
            .getPerChange());
}

if(((position * 3) + 2) <= getCount()){
    holder.txtName2.setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 2)
            .getStockCode());
    holder.txtCityState2
            .setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 2).getLtp());
    holder.txtPhone2.setText(searchArrayList.get((position * 3) + 2)
            .getPerChange());
}
```